# Compiling this sample Teensy source file

Tags: compilation, arduino, microcontroller

I can't seem to get the `blinky.c` program for [Teensy](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) 2.0 to compile. Here is the error:

```
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega32u4         -I. -gdwarf-2 -DF_CPU=16000000UL -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -ffunction-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=./blinky.lst  -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF .dep/blinky.o.d blinky.c -o blinky.o
blinky.c: In function 'main':
blinky.c:69:12: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:72:11: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c: In function 'morse_character':
blinky.c:83:3: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:88:3: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:90:3: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:93:2: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:100:4: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:103:4: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c:110:2: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
blinky.c: In function 'morse_P':
blinky.c:125:2: error: variable '__c' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
make: *** [blinky.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I suppose variable 'c' must be const. :)

Comment: this is supposed to be the sample code... so I'm sure it works. I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I was trying to be funny, but at the same time, the error messages are clear: you are trying to force a read/write variable into read-only section, and it makes the compiler unhappy. There is a chance that the example code was written for a less fussy compiler, and wasn't updated for the new one. It is also possible that there is a compiler switch that would stop the error (though it would have been in the `Makefile`). I'd just modify the code, sample or not.

Comment: @user988566 - vhallac is right, progmem (http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) variables must be defined as constants.  The sample code is wrong.

Comment: I would guess there is an incompatibility between your version of `avr-gcc` and the example.

Comment: The sample code [here](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/blinky.zip) has been updated, sort of. `blinky.c` compiles correctly out of the box, as all `PROGMEM` variables have been updated to be `const`, however `usb_debug_only.c` still requires editing to compile correctly.